# Open screen in terminal after user login

Tags: linux, terminal, command, gnu-screen

When a user logins to my Debian server using e.g. Putty, I need to perform the following:

1. It will automatically execute command `screen -r MyWindow`, and
2. the user won't be able to leave the screen window, so I want the user to have disabled all commands.

How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe it's better if you ask [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Write your command to/etc/init.d/rc.local,and ln to all rc.X

```
vi /etc/init.d/rc.local
i
screen -r MyWindow
:wq
ln -sf /etc/init.d/rc.local /etc/init.d/rc.3 (default)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your script under /etc/prodile or put your command under .bash_profile of home directory of user